# Remove scrollbars from sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the scrollbars on my sidebar, you can have a look at this bootply:

```
http://www.bootply.com/DbyYVRupPJ
```

I have tried some stuff like this

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q)

```
#sidebar{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100%;
}
```

but I can't get it working properly

Anybody able to help me out? :)

Edit: The scroll function should still be active

Comment: Which scrollbar you want to remove horizontal or vertical ?

Comment: I want to remove both scrollbars, but keep it scrollable. The scrollbars looks just ugly :-D

Comment: Check solution from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll Same example  given Gnanadurai A in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like the following code:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q/671/
or http://jsfiddle.net/qcv5Q/672/ if you don't want to have visible scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

Add the last propierty "overflow-y: hidden". Or if you want to remove the x-axis so.. overflow-x: hidden.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 70px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    overflow-y:hidden;  /* NEW ONE */
}
```

Or if you want that to adjust to the content you have to write:

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

Comment: Yes, but afterwards the sidebar isn't scrollable anymore?

Comment: That's right. No more scrollable. If you want the depend of the content you have to add: overflow-y: auto; and this will adjust to your content.